# Extracting Time from Timestamp in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am using Redshift and am looking to extract the time from the timestamp.

Here is the timestamp: 2017-10-31 23:30:00

and I would just like to get the time as 23:30:00

I tried using `cast(the_timestamp_column as time)` but ran into this error message:

`error message: Function ""time"(timestamp without time zone)" not supported.`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`to_char`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_CHAR.html) with an appropriate format mask to extract the time component of your timestamp:

```
select to_char(the_timestamp_column, 'HH24:MI:SS')
from your_table;
```

## Demo

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response =)

Comment: What I was looking for an hour.